# Windows Phone Emulator not displaying unicode characters

Tags: unicode, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I am developing a windows phone app that uses unicode chars. The xamll displays the characters fine. But when I run the emulator, the good ole squares show up! I tried sending the font with isolated storage even. What can I do? If the app was to be installed into a windows phone device, would it look like my xaml page or the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Emulator is closer to a device than Visual Studio designer, so if you can't see these characters on the emulator then you won't see them on the device.

I guess you're using some custom font. To use it, you have to embed it in your app. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2014/03/15/how-to-use-custom-font-in-windows-phone-8-application.aspx) you can find out how to do it.